What is the reason for 29.9kW PV inverters, when there are 30kW rated ones?
I have noticed various inverter manufacturers offering 29.9kW PV inverters as well as 30kW units. I assume this is due to a regulation or norm for inverters rated below 30kW, but I cannot find anything relevant regarding this topic. I hope someone can shed some light on this... thanks!

(Disclaimer: I do not work in California)
It looks like that number is what California's Public Utilities Commission has determined is the threshold for whether a system can, by itself, create detrimental effects in the wider grid. See here.
Installations with a nameplate capacity of <30 kVA are apparently exempt from many reporting requirements. See here also.

It's very easy to insert hyperlinks into text here instead of pasting long and ugly weblinks. Just select the words you want to become a hyperlink, click on the Hyperlink icon then paste the weblink into the dialogue box. Looks infinitely better, easier to read.

I would say its also a good idea to make those links be archive.org-links. if not, the answer is basically useless within any arbitrary amount of time. Links die all the time
